# One processor is working wierdly

Tags: windows-10, cpu, fan, cpu-usage

My Overall CPU condition is fine, but one of my processors (the first one) seems to be heavily working (and I can feel that from my fan noise and the heat).

[image: task man]

I checked `task manager` and `resource monitor` to see which process is taking that much power. Found nothing. I guessed that maybe not all the processes are actually shown in resource monitor so I installed *Process Lasso* and *Process Explorer* (both are more or less similar to Windows' `resource monitor`). Still found nothing. I also set all affinities to 1-7, meaning that all my processes can be start on all my CPUs except the first one. Yet, there is a huge load on my first CPU. 
[image: resmon]

By some research, I found that it may be the case that my first CPU's clock is somehow set to be really high, which I guess, means more power consumption, more fan speed and more heat (I don't have a concrete knowledge about the clock, so not sure if my guess is really correct). Noting that my *Maximum Frequency* in `resource monitor`, is actually suggesting that my CPU (don't indicates which one) is working with nearly 130% of maximum frequency (= boost speed/base speed *100 = 3.6/2.6 *100 = 138 %) or my maximum boost speed frequency to be more precise. So I tried to change my `maximum processor state` to something considerably less than 100% (say 50) to see If there is any difference in heat and noise. Nothing again even after reboot.

[image: Power Plan]

My system is dual-boot and I don't have that problem in my other OS (Ubuntu 16.04). No noise or heat.

So here are my questions:

1. Is my first CPU really working that much? If so, then how it's possible to have such normal average CPU usage (the average is incredibly close tho the mean of all other CPUs)?
2. Why affinity change doesn't made any difference on the CPU usage?
3. The CPU usage of all my processes is less than what is actually is being used. Look at resource monitor picture: I have selected all the processes and now the orange line shows the amount of CPU that is taken by them. I checked the same in safe mode. Orange line, exactly coincides the total usage in safe mode. So I'm suspecting that something is happening in my normal boot. What may be the reason and how I can solve it?

My system is:

- Intel core i7 - 4720 HQ  2.6 GHz upto 3.6
- Windows 10 (64 bit)
- NVidia GTX 950 M

---

PS:

This screenshot, shows the *Process Lasso*'s interface. Those 8 green bars on upper right show my CPU usage. Also the column called *Rules*, indicates the affinities on the processes.

[image: Screenshot of my desktop]

Comment: Please stop asking the same question again and again. @harrymc already gave you a detailed troubleshooting guide the last time which you haven’t fully responded to and there’s not much else anyone can do to help. If you follow all the existing advice and can show that it still doesn’t help then you will have a case for getting your earlier question reopened.

Comment: @JamesP I don't meant to do that. Actually, I think my last question was set duplicated wrongly since I intended to address some other issues rather what the post is directed to. I edited my last post and added complimentary information, but at the end, I saw that I've changed the original post a lot, so I decided to post another question as it was written in the guide box just below the post. Please inform me if you think that I'd better to edit my last post instead of posting a new question in this particular problem.

Comment: Well, please at least delete the very first one at https://superuser.com/questions/1308293/only-one-core-cpu-is-primarily-used as it seems redundant now.